# Axios request from React app to Node.js backend blocked by CORS

Tags: node.js, axios, cors

I've tried to make request from my fresh React app to backend, but got CORS policy error.[image]
Requests straight to backend works well, but from another server it fails.

Here are my code:

*backend*

**Controller**

```
googleAuth(req: Request, res: Response): void {
        const authUrl = this.userService.generateGoogleRedirectUrl();
        res.redirect(authUrl);
    }

async googleCallback(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        const code = req.query.code;
        const successLogin = await this.userService.signGoogleUser(
            code as string
        );
        res.cookie("refreshToken", successLogin.refreshToken, {
            httpOnly: true,
        });
        res.cookie("accessToken", successLogin.accessToken, {
            secure: true,
        });
        console.log(successLogin);
        res.json({ msg: "success" });
    }
```

**UserService**

```
generateGoogleRedirectUrl(): string {
        const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI
        );
        return oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
            access_type: "offline",
            prompt: "consent",
            scope: [
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
            ],
        });
    }

    async signGoogleUser(code: string): Promise<Tokens> {
        const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
            process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            process.env.GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI
        );
        const { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code);
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        const oauth2 = google.oauth2({ version: "v2", auth: oauth2Client });
        const userInfo = await oauth2.userinfo.v2.me.get();
        const data = {
            firstName: userInfo.data.given_name as string,
            lastName: userInfo.data.family_name as string,
            email: userInfo.data.email as string,
            oauth2Id: userInfo.data.id as string,
        };
        const existedUser = await this.dynamoDBService.find(data.email);
        if (existedUser) {
            const accessToken = await this.signAccessToken(
                existedUser.email,
                existedUser.id!
            );
            const refreshToken = await this.signRefreshToken(
                existedUser.email,
                existedUser.id!
            );
            return { accessToken, refreshToken };
        } else {
            await this.dynamoDBService.create(data);
            const user = await this.dynamoDBService.find(data.email);
            const accessToken = await this.signAccessToken(
                user!.email,
                user!.id!
            );
            const refreshToken = await this.signRefreshToken(
                user!.email,
                user!.id!
            );
            return { accessToken, refreshToken };
        }
    }
```

On frontend there are simply axios GET request to backend, but I must admit, that I configured headers for CORS

```
const instance = axios.create(
{
        baseURL: "http://localhost:8000",
        headers: {
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS',   
      }
  })

export default instance;
```

On backend I've imported CORS library and apply it to my app by `app.use(cors())`

I'm not using Passport library too btw.

Comment: Headers that start with `Access-Control-Allow-` do not belong in requests. You can safely remove them.